# Where is POST Payload Information Located in the request object?

Tags: html, json, node.js, post

I would have thought this was a trivial question, and that the answer would be "in the body"... yet it doesn't seem to be the case.

Take this example where we have a website that will collect data and then send a POST to a listener website that will receive the information:

Here is the html for the POST website:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Form POST Site</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm(){document.getElementById('form1').action = document.getElementById('server').value;}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.style1 {width: 100%;}
.style2 {width: 429px;}
#server { width: 254px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<H3>Form POST Site</H3>
<form method="POST" id="form1" onSubmit="submitForm()">
<table class="style1">
<tr>
<td class="style2">
Username:</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="username" value="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="style2">
Server: </td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="server" name="server" value="http://" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="style2">
<input type="submit" name="submittable" value="Go" /></td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
```

And here is the node.js code for the listener website:

```html
/*global require,console*/

var xml = require('xml');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require ('express-xml-bodyparser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser()); // add a middleware (so that express can parse request.body's json)

app.post('/', (request, response) => {
  /*response.send(request.body);*/
  console.log(request.body);
  response.json("received");
});

app.listen(1123);
```

So accessing the POST website, and setting the IP address of the listener as the target, we can see exactly what is being sent.

And that is what is confusing me. The request.body is empty.

Not only that, when I look at the entirety of the request, I don't see the text value that I entered for "username" anywhere.

I'd like to be able to receive the "username" text string in my node.js code and do something with it... but I don't know where to find it.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok. So I get that. But no matter the body-parser I use (and I've tried two different versions) I still get empty body values...

Comment: In your case, you are posting url-encoded body. So, to parse that you have to use `
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))`

Comment: I just noticed that you are using `express-xml-bodyparser`, not `body-parser`. That's why `request.body` is empty.

Comment: Actually my original version had body-parser. It didn't work any better...

Comment: It worked perfectly in my case. I tried and verified the code I posted.

Comment: Darn it. You are right. I changed the body-parser and now it works. Not sure what was going on earlier, but it is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, `request.body` is empty. `body-parser` (or probably related modules) parses the request body, depending upon the content-type and compression, and puts the body into `request.body`.

You are using `express-xml-bodyparser` that can parse `xml` in `POST`, but not the regular `form` data usually `url-encoded`. So, you can use `body-parser` and get the `form` fields.

e.g.

```
var xml = require('xml');
var express = require('express');
var xmlbodyParser = require ('express-xml-bodyparser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();


app.use(xmlbodyParser()); // add a middleware (so that express can parse request.body's xml)
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })) //add a middle (so that express can parse request.body's urlencoded dataa)

app.post('/', (request, response) => {
   /*response.send(request.body);*/
   console.log(request.body);
   response.json("received");
});

app.listen(1123);
```